# .val() not assigning return to new variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

After this zip will remain at 0 no matter what the value of "input" is. I suspect it has something to do with apiAddress not updating zip after the new value is assigned to zip. Can any one explain what is happening?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    zip = 0;
    apiAddress = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=" + zip;

    $("#submit").on("click", function() {
        zip = $("input").val();
        $("#temperature").html(apiAddress);
    });
});
```

Comment: You're updating `zip`, but not `apiAddress`. Either do what Mojtaba suggests, or do `apiAddress = function(){ return "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=" + zip; };` and `$("#temperature").html(apiAddress());` https://jsfiddle.net/ff75jess/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the zip variable to your url in the wrong place. Also, it's better to care about variable scope. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var zip = 0;

    $("#submit").on("click", function() {
        zip = $("input").val();
        apiAddress = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=" + zip;
        $("#temperature").html(apiAddress);
    });
});
```

Comment: I feel so silly now. I had a conceptual misunderstanding of how variable assignment works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's good practice to use `console.log()` to see what is being returned by `$("input").val();`. Add the following line to your code and check your browser's console to see the value being logged after submiting:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    zip = 0;

    $("#submit").on("click", function() {
        console.log( $("input").val() ); //Add this line
        zip = $("input").val();
        apiAddress = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=" + zip;
        $("#temperature").html(apiAddress);
    });
});
```

There might be more than one `<input>` tag in your html. Try giving it an id like `<input id="inp1">` and change your javascript code to:

```
zip = $("#inp1").val();
```